# python share a memory between two modules using oop

Tags: python, oop

I have three modules

(1)mem.py

```
memory = {}

class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global memory
        self.internal = memory

    def set(self,key,value):
        self.internal[key]=value
    def printmem(self):
        print self.internal
```

(2)computer1.py

```
from mem import test

comp1 = test()

comp1.set(1,2)
comp1.printmem()
```

(3)computer2.py

```
from mem import test

comp2 = test()

comp2.set(3,4)
comp2.printmem()
```

Now at the interactive shell I run computer1.py and then computer2.py. The result is not what I want. When I run computer2.py, I want the comp2.printmem() to print {1:2,3:4} as memory is global and it should carry {1:2} from comp1 into comp2 but it only prints {3:4}. How can I fix this ?

Comment: What do you mean you "run" computer1 and then computer2?  Do you mean you're running them from from a system prompt, or from inside the Python interpreter?  If from inside the Python interpreter, how?

Comment: Exactly. If you are running both the script in an interactive shell i.e. the same process, then you should get your expected result (unless you are doing something funny like reloading a module).

Comment: @BrenBarn: I go to the terminal (not the inside of interpreter) and type " >>> python comp1.py " and then " >>> python comp2.py "

Comment: @Vaidik: I'm importing the same module into two different files. But I have declared memory as global variable. Evenif the test module instantiated twice as comp1 and comp2, the global memory is the same everywhere. But I don't get memory as {1:2,3:4} when I run the comp2.py after comp1.py

Comment: @LuckyStarr: Then you're running two separate programs that share nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not right @LuckyStarr. Every process gets its own slice of memory. When you run `python computer1.py`, the Python interpreter loads `computer1.py`, which imports `mem.py`. The Python interpreter for this call uses some amount of memory, wherein your global variable of `mem.py` resides. As soon as `computer1.py` has finished executing, the process exits cleanly, releasing all the used memory.

Now when you run `computer2.py`, the same thing happens all over again i.e. `computer2.py` gets loaded in a new Python process, which gets new memory, which loads `mem.py` and then your created objects from all your modules live in the memory for the lifetime of that Python process.

`mem.py` does not have its separate share of memory. Its the Python process that has a particular share memory, the Python process is responsible for loading all the modules including `mem.py` and other modules like `computer1.py`. And the objects created by the loaded in the span of this Python process are persisted in the memory only until the process is running.

And you are anyways running `computer1.py` and `computer2.py` as separate Python processes - they don't have access to each other's memory until they decide to do so using some other techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're attempting to share objects across separate and unrelated processes.  For simply sharing objects among processes sharing a common Python ancestor you could use [Value or Array Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) from the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module (in the standard libraries).

However, to share objects (or, more generally, memory) among processes which were not spawned by a common Python process ... which are not "children" of the Python program instance that you executed) you'd have to use either the [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module (from the standard libraries) or some implementation of [SysV IPC](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/) ... and you'd need to write some wrapper around these lower level facilities in order to serialize and deserialize objects into them.

I don't know if [POSH](http://poshmodule.sourceforge.net/posh/html/posh.html) is being maintained (not listed on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and last update on the website seems to date from about eleven years ago).  However, that might be a starting point for your own work.

All of that aside I'd suggest that you consider a different approach.  Use [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Redis is a key/value store with support for a number of datatypes as values and a number of server-side operations on those values, and keys.  It's generally considered to be a NoSQL tool, and has optional persistence (filesystem) and replication (network, slaves).  Additionally it supports some "message bus" operations [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

The [Python Redis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/2.10.1) support makes it almost trivial to share [lists](http://redis.io/commands#list), [dictionaries](http://redis.io/commands#hash),[strings and integers](http://redis.io/commands#string), and [sets](http://redis.io/commands#string).  Also some of the operations and Redis semantics for lists make it trivial to use them as distributed [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)-like objects.

(Additionally any other object types that you could "[pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)" can be passed through Redis values, either as strings on a key, or fields in a "hash" (dictionary)).

On top of that Redis supports some types which have no direct native Python analogues (such as [sorted sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) and [HyperLogLog](http://antirez.com/news/75). Also some additional semantics can be added to Redis via its [scripting](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-and-scripting.html) feature implementing server-side embedded [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) handling).

Using Redis one can share objects among unrelated processes, but also distribute them across networks to other systems.  Redis is often used only as a caching system (a sort of non-distributed [memcache](http://memcached.org/).  You could also use memcache as an unreliable data store (in the sense that any values set on your memcached could be expired at any time due to competing process activity).

As you step beyond inter-process communications and object sharing (note: any IPC can be an object sharing mechanism using serialization/deserialization) ... there are other options you can consider.  Basically any relationship database (SQL RDBMS) or NoSQL system can be used and might offer performance comparable to what you might implement over `mmap`.  (Usually is the serialization and deserialization which will be your bottleneck; and a typical multi-core system will have more than enough CPU power to host your Python processes and any of the common RDBMS nor NoSQL (single node) systems.

Comment: As I was writing this I did search around for OO wrappers around shared and distributed memory subsystems for Python.  I was sure I'd seen some in the past.  But none of them seem to be actively maintained and easily found at this point.